# I replaced a pdf file but google searches for the node turn up the old pdf file

Tags: files

I replaced a downloadable pdf file that was uploaded to one of the nodes on my website. But a google search of the item still goes straight to the old file. I've tried deleting the node completely and recreating it with the new file, but it still won't work. (The file name is the same, it's just the content that's augmented). The google search will direct properly on my laptop, but not on my ipad. I can't figure out if this is a drupal issue or a google issue or a browser issue (I deleted all cookies and history on my ipad before googling, but it still won't work)--can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like google hasn't refreshed your site yet.  You could do a 301 redirect from your old file name or url to a new one if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Drupal File System - determined at Admin/Config/Media/File System - there are 3 directories that store files uploaded to your Drupal site. I would recommend navigating to each of these directories to find your (old) .PDF file and deleting it ...

If you want to keep the old PDF, consider renaming it ...